# "Took off" or "taken off"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, sentence, syntactic-analysis

> My boss was talking to me. How could I have just **taken off**?
>
> My boss was talking to me. How could I have just **took off**?"

Which one is correct. (or are they both wrong?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first is correct.

After "have", it would be "I have taken off".

Without, it would be "I took off".

Comment: So why exactly is *How could I just took off* not valid?

Answer (score 2):

The correct one is:

> My boss was talking to me. How could I have just **taken off**?

Let me explain why this one is correct: the sentence uses "could have"; "could have" takes past participle; "took off" is past tense, so it cannot be used; "taken off" is past participle, so it could be used.

I think I am clear now.